# Setting Text in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, parsing

I have to parse an xml file and display the required fields in GUI i have used sax parser and getting desired output in console but all the values are not displayed in GUI except vname  i have kept my code below.

enter code here

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class exp1 {
    public static String vname = "";
    public static String vvalue;
    public static String vtype = null;
    private final JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name");
    private final JLabel lblType = new JLabel("Type");
    private final JLabel lblValue = new JLabel("Value");
    private final JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Results");
    private final TextArea textArea_3 = new TextArea();
    private final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    private final TextArea textArea_1 = new TextArea();

public  exp1 (String a){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 13));

    frame.setSize(new Dimension(668, 517));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    this.lblName.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    this.lblName.setBounds(86, 60, 56, 17);

    frame.getContentPane().add(this.lblName);

    this.lblType.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    this.lblType.setBounds(519, 60, 56, 17);

    frame.getContentPane().add(this.lblType);
    this.lblValue.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    this.lblValue.setBounds(297, 61, 46, 14);

    frame.getContentPane().add(this.lblValue);
    this.lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
    this.lblNewLabel.setBounds(34, 11, 86, 38);

    frame.getContentPane().add(this.lblNewLabel);
    this.textArea_3.setBounds(27, 110, 212, 230);

    frame.getContentPane().add(this.textArea_3);
    this.textArea.setBounds(438, 110, 193, 230);

    frame.getContentPane().add(this.textArea);

    this.textArea_1.setBounds(256, 110, 168, 230);

    frame.getContentPane().add(this.textArea_1);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String argv[]) {



exp1 xm = new exp1(null);



try {

    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

boolean bfname = false;
boolean blname = false;
boolean bnname = false;
String nameAttribute;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
    String qName, Attributes attributes)
throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("TYP")) {
        bfname = true;
        }

    nameAttribute = attributes.getValue("Name");

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("VALUE")) {
        blname = true;
        }

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("VARIABLENAME")) {
        bnname = true;
        }
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
String qName) throws SAXException {
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
throws SAXException {

    if (bfname) {
        System.out.println("Type : "+ new String(ch, start, length));
        bfname = false;
        vtype = new String(ch, start, length);
        // VALUE HERE IS ONLY DISPLAYED ONCE IN JFRAME
        }

    if (nameAttribute != null && !nameAttribute.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Name : " + nameAttribute);
        vname+=nameAttribute+ ", " +"\n";
        }

    if (blname) {

        vvalue = new String(ch, start, length);
        System.out.println("Value:" + Double.valueOf(vvalue));
        // VALUE HERE IS ONLY DISPLAYED ONCE IN JFRAME
        blname = false;
        }
}
};
saxParser.parse(new File("filepath.xml"), handler);  //for ex :-"New Folder\\VG_MachineData.xml"
xm.textArea_3.setText(vname);
xm.textArea.setText(vtype);
xm.textArea_1.setText(new Double(vvalue).toString());


} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}


//xml tags
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HMI_Data Version="1.0" MaschinenNR.="XXXXXX" Date="21-10-2009">
   <VarGroup Name="VG_MachineData">
      <Variable Name="Mold1.sv_rMoldStroke">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>6.000000e+02</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxSpeedFwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>5.000000e+01</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxSpeedBwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>5.000000e+01</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxPressureFwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>1.450000e+02</Value>
      </Variable>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) as your code doesn't make sense.  I can guess at your problem, but that's just going to waste each others time...

Comment: I have edited the question with full code and below is the xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major issue is the use of `setText` on your `JTextArea`s.  This will overwrite any text already in the fields and replace it with what you pass.

Since most of your variable assignments didn't involve concatenation, you were only setting the last value of the variable.

Instead, you could update the fields directly using `append` within the method.

```
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    System.out.println("characters " + new String(ch, start, length));
    if (bfname) {
        System.out.println("Type : " + new String(ch, start, length));
        bfname = false;
        vtype = new String(ch, start, length);
        xm.textArea_3.append(vtype + "\n");
    }

    if (nameAttribute != null && !nameAttribute.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Name : " + nameAttribute);
        xm.textArea.append(nameAttribute + "\n");
    }

    if (blname) {

        vvalue = new String(ch, start, length);
        System.out.println("Value:" + Double.valueOf(vvalue));
        // VALUE HERE IS ONLY DISPLAYED ONCE IN JFRAME
        xm.textArea_1.append(new Double(vvalue).toString() + "\n");
        blname = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Programmer Thanks twice. May i know what was the issue in my code it worked perfectly fine when i changed according to you.

Comment: The major issue was your assignment's of your variables, you were doing things like `vvalue = new String(ch, start, length);`, which means the `vvalue` was always only going to be equal to the last value assigned to it.  I think `vname` was the only one you were concatenating...

Comment: Programmer Thanks Bro.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a sample code .Try this kind of solution

```
package sax;
```

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SaxTest {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
            String elementName = null;

            public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                    String qName, Attributes attributes)
                    throws SAXException {
                /*
                 * this method is called once the parser meets a start
                 * element and you should implement here how your code
                 * should behave when a start element is found.The name of
                 * the start element is the parameter qName and the
                 * attributes of that element is under attributes parameter.
                 */
                elementName = qName;
            }

            public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                    String qName) throws SAXException {
                /*
                 * this method is called once the parser meets an end
                 * element and you should implement here how your code
                 * should behave when an end element is found.The name of
                 * the end element is the parameter qName.
                 */
            }

            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
                    throws SAXException {
                /*
                 * this method is called once the parser encounters text
                 * under an element.
                 */
                if (elementName.equals("vname")) {
                 //set the vname textarea here
                }
                if (elementName.equals("vtype")) {
                    //set the vtype textarea here
                }
                if (elementName.equals("vvalue")) {
                    //set the vvalue textarea here
                }
            }
        };

        // for specifying the xml document
        saxParser.parse("/home/sanjaya/Desktop/a.xml", handler);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is when all the values are parsed the displayed string are only in vname and of vtype and vvalue are not getting set in GUI.I have kept my complete code with xml above